# How can I transfer context variable into a html bound javascript code in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

I have write down a view:

```
def Country_names(request):
    c_list = []
    for c_name in c_names:
        c_list.append(c_name)
    return render(request, 'DATAPLO/Country_list.html', {'c_list':c_list})
```

This view transfers a list/array to template further in my html template it try to convert this python variable into javascript array variable.

```
<script>
//variable defined to store "c_list" array 
 var c_names = {{c_list}}
//try to access array items like this
 c_names[0]
</script>
```

But his method is not working in my case how can I do this, I have explore dfew similar threads on the web but nothing is working in my case.

thanks

Comment: The `script` should be inside the HTML, **not** in a separate `.js` file. Works pretty well if it's inside the HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer which includes a Country model

models.py:

```
class Country(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So if your country model looks like this, we need to make that into a list of strings to be converted to json.

```
import json

def Country_names(request):
    c_list = Country.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
    return render(request, 'DATAPLO/Country_list.html', {'c_list':json.dumps(c_list)})
```

And then output in HTML. Remember to mark it safe, so it doesn't get escaped

```
<script>
    //variable defined to store "c_list" array
    var c_names = {{c_list|safe}}
</script>
```

Comment: showing strange error: TypeError at /DATAPLO/
<QuerySet [<Country: India>, <Country: pakistan>]> is not JSON serializable.

Comment: Ahh ok, so you then we need a list comprehension after all. I will update the answer

Comment: @ Sune can you explain what did we use "country.name " during list comprehensions

Comment: A better approach would be to use values_list if all you need is just names

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but basically what we did during the list comprehension is to loop over all the countries and add their name property to a new list

Comment: Added the missing, flat=True to the values_list method call. But really you should point out what the error is, rather than just stating that there is an error

Answer (score 0):

You can use [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)
to get the list of country names.

```
import json
def getCountryNames(request):
    country_names = list(Country.objects.values_list('name', flat=True))
    return render(request, 'DATAPLO/Country_list.html', {'country_names':json.dumps(country_names)})
```

rest is same as @Sune's answer